# Tailwindcss autocomplete on Laravel project not showing

Tags: php, laravel, autocomplete, tailwind-css

My tailwindcss autocomplete on a laravel 8 project does not show.

I first create the project with

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel=8.6 Taskit
```

and then install and initialize breeze for authentication from the this link: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze

which automatically initialize tailwind with laravel mix and vite.

But there's a error first that I have to encounter, e.g. changing style link for tailwind in **app.blade.php** and **guest.blade.php [image]**

And the project is working fine.

But Tailwindcss autocomplete do not work. I have tried on a HTML file and still not working. I have installed the tailwind extensions for vscode and in other project(not laravel) work fine with autocomplete. But in this project the styling can compile but there's no autocomplete

Can you help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npx tailwindcss init` to create twildinw.config.js on the project root.

If still doesn't add below config to vscode setting JSON to associate blade file to html

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.blade.php": "html"
}
```

Comment: I already had tailwind config file when initialize breeze and the files.associations rules do not work

Comment: try ctrl  + space to show auto-complete options, it will not show if there are too many matches.

Double check tailwind extension setting, Ctrl + ,  to open vscode settings and search Tailwind CSS: Suggestions, see if the "Enable autocomplete suggestions" is enabled

Comment: the settings for "enable autocomplete suggestions" for tailwind are already checked and there's still no autocomplete. I tried hitting "ctrl" + "space" many times and still the autocomplete not showing